# I am getting exception while creating session with stripe in java 17 and in 11 version it is working fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, stripe-payments

I am getting an exception while creating a session with Stripe.

The create method returns the following exception:

```
Failed making field 'java.net.Proxy#type' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
```

```
public Session createSession(Long scheduleId, CardPaymentDetailDto paymentSessionDto) {
        List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add(paymentSessionDto.getTourImage());
        try {
            SessionCreateParams params =
                    SessionCreateParams.builder()
                            .addPaymentMethodType(SessionCreateParams.PaymentMethodType.CARD)
                            .addLineItem(
                                    SessionCreateParams.LineItem.builder()
                                            .setName(paymentSessionDto.getTourName())
                                            .setDescription(paymentSessionDto.getTourDesc())
                                            .setAmount((long) (paymentSessionDto.getAmount() * 100))
                                            .setCurrency(paymentSessionDto.getCurrency())
                                            .addAllImage(elements)
                                            .setQuantity(1L)
                                            .build())
                            .setSuccessUrl(GlobalValues.CEHCKOUT_WEB_PORTAL + "checkout/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}" + "&schedule_id=" + scheduleId + "&group_id=" + paymentSessionDto.getTourPaymentDetail().getGroupId())
                            .setCancelUrl(GlobalValues.CEHCKOUT_WEB_PORTAL + "checkout/cancel?tourId=" + paymentSessionDto.getTourPaymentDetail().getTourId())
                            .setCustomerEmail(paymentSessionDto.getOwnerEmail())
                            //.setCustomer("cus_HGaPmKuUCOYWrj")
                            .build();
            Session session =Session.create(params);// this line throw exception
            return session;
        } catch (StripeException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The `session.create` method throws the above mentioned exception in Java 17, but works fine in Java 11.

Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
2023-02-03T15:13:30.051+05:30 ERROR 27388 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] com.experience.config.StripeClient       : Failed making field 'java.net.Proxy#type' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.

com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.net.Proxy#type' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getDelegateAdapter(Gson.java:635) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.stripe.model.PaymentSourceTypeAdapterFactory.create(PaymentSourceTypeAdapterFactory.java:31) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getDelegateAdapter(Gson.java:635) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.stripe.model.BalanceTransactionSourceTypeAdapterFactory.create(BalanceTransactionSourceTypeAdapterFactory.java:34) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getDelegateAdapter(Gson.java:635) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.stripe.model.BalanceTransactionSourceTypeAdapterFactory.create(BalanceTransactionSourceTypeAdapterFactory.java:34) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getDelegateAdapter(Gson.java:635) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.stripe.model.BalanceTransactionSourceTypeAdapterFactory.create(BalanceTransactionSourceTypeAdapterFactory.java:32) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:295) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1213) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1319) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1261) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.handleApiError(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:133) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:61) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:179) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.stripe.model.checkout.Session.create(Session.java:348) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.stripe.model.checkout.Session.create(Session.java:341) ~[stripe-java-20.26.0.jar:20.26.0]
    at com.experience.config.StripeClient.createNewSession(StripeClient.java:359) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.experience.controller.TransactionController.saveFirstPaymentDetailAndSession(TransactionController.java:179) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:913) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:547) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at com.experience.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.net.Proxy$Type java.net.Proxy.type accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @44bc069d
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:35) ~[gson-2.10.jar:na]
    ... 167 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you please give more details about this exception? what code is generating this exception with a complete Stacktrace? What Stripe API are you calling?

Comment: @os4m37 now I have shared all the required information

Comment: Thanks for sharing, you need to upgrade your Stripe SDK if you want to use newer Java version. Try this Stripe version 22.7.0. You may need to update some of your implementations.

Comment: I have tried but nothing is working i am getting same exception

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue using your code, with Java 11. But when upgrading to com.stripe:stripe-java:22.7.0 with Java 17 the issue is resolved

Comment: Or at least version com.stripe:stripe-java:20.91.0 which is tested on both Java 16 and 17
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#20910---2021-12-09